# How to determine if text is inside an anchor?

Tags: php

I have this app I am working on where I have to truncate some text. The problem is that sometimes the text has anchor tags in it. And if I truncate where there is an anchor tag, it messes-up the rest of my HTML. Here is an example:

```
<a href="">And here is some text</a>
```

Now, if the truncating cuts the text off so it looks like the following, there is a problem:

```
<a href="">And here is so
```

Of course, the text is not this simple. It can be thousands of characters long with any number of anchors in it.

So, is there a way to determine if the last of the text contains an anchor so I can manually add a closing tag?

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you have to get the text between the all the anchor tags, right ?????
Is that your question ???

Comment: Would be useful to see your truncating function as I'm not too clear on where you are and where you want to go

Comment: Not all the anchors. just the last one if the text is cut off before the </a>

Comment: Yeah, the function is this: $text = substr($text, 0, 100). :)

Comment: in short: manipulate it as HTML(dom), not as plain text. truncate the text nodes.

Comment: You have to use either [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) to remove the HTML so that there will be no problem with truncating. Or build/look for a function that will close the tags.

Comment: That's an interesting idea Karoly. Do yo mean use something like DOmDocument?

Comment: Sure you need to do this server-side, wouldnt a $("a").text() be useful to you? can you please provide more details?

Comment: Someone posted a link, but the message appears to be gone now. That seems to be doing the trick. Thanks.